# ASP.NET returns incorrect data from oData Controller

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.NET Web API app using Oracle's Entity Framework driver. I have an entity defined for a view as follows:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "PHASE_TWO"."EDIPRODUCT" ("ID", "STK_NUM", "TITLE", "ISBN", "UPC", "ITEMNO", "LONGFORMAT", "ABRIDGED", "WEB_TITLES_ID", "OCLC", "GENRE", "RELYEAR", "ORIG_REL", "LANG", "ORIG_STKNUM", "PUBLISHER", "PEOPLELIST", "SALES_ORG", "NOT_AVAIL") AS 
  SELECT sap_product.id,
    sap_product.stk_num,
    sap_product.longdesc AS title,
    sap_product.isbn,
    sap_product.upc,
    sap_product.itemno,
    sap_product.longformat,
    sap_product.abridged,
    mwt_product.web_titles_id,
    mwt_product.oclc,
    mwt_product.genre,
    mwt_product.RELYEAR,
    sap_product.orig_rel,
    sap_product.lang,
    sap_product.orig_stknum,
    UPPER (publisher.name) publisher,
    (SELECT LISTAGG (p.FULLNAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (
    ORDER BY pp.rank) AS People
    FROM people p
    JOIN product_people pp
    ON p.id          = pp.peopleid
    WHERE pp.stk_num = sap_product.stk_num
    GROUP BY pp.STK_NUM
    ) PeopleList, 
    sppg.PRICING_TYPE as sales_org, 
    sap_product.not_avail
FROM sap_product
JOIN mwt_product ON sap_product.stk_num = mwt_product.stk_num
JOIN publisher ON mwt_product.publisherid        = publisher.id
JOIN SAP_PRODUCT_PRICING_GROUP sppg on sppg.STK_NUM = mwt_product.stk_num and sppg.MARKED_FOR_DELETION = 0
WHERE mwt_product.WEB_PRODUCTS_ID > 0;
```

This view works as expected in SQL Developer. My getEDIPRODUCT function (yes, it's VB.NET) in my controller is as follows:

```
' GET: odata/EDIPRODUCTs
        <EnableQuery>
        Function GetEDIPRODUCT() As IQueryable(Of EDIPRODUCT)
            Dim results As IQueryable
            results = db.EDIPRODUCT
            For Each _product In results
                Console.Write(_product)

            Next
            Return results
        End Function
```

I just added the for loop in order to inspect the results. What I see when I inspect the results is the same product record is returned for each row. The value for the ID is duplicate and the only other field that should have variant values (sppg.PRICING_TYPE as sales_org) also just repeats.

I have other views where this does not occur. The correct number of records are always returned, but the first record retrieved is always just repeated in each row of the result set. Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Did you copy and paste to create this? If so, it is likely you missed one or more changes in the query.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I pasted the query here, but the view was added to the model using the designer and is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never actually resolved this issue and am still interested in why this fails, but I rewrote the portion of the app that uses this view to use OData's $expand to retrieve the related data.